# Skipping incompatible error

Tags: c, linux, contiki, cflags

I downloaded nettle 3.0 cryptography library and i compiled it on ubuntu.
I ran an example and it s working fine on ubuntu.
I added the compiled static library file (libnettle.a) to the my project
makefile in contiki ,by simply adding:

```
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/lib/ -lnettle
```

When i try to compile the node code , i get this

```
/usr/local/msp430/bin/../lib/gcc/msp430/4.7.0/../../.*./../msp430/bin/ld:skipping incompatible /usr/l*ocal/lib//libnettle.a when searching for -lnettle
/usr/local/msp430/bin/../lib/gcc/msp430/4.7.0/../../.*./../msp430/bin/ld: cannot find -lnettle*
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
rm obj_sky/contiki-sky-main.o test_nettle.co
Process returned error code 2

make: *** [test_nettle.sky] Error 1
```

Should i add -m32 flag or what ?

If yes what flag ? CFLAG ?

and by the way , the nettle library is 32bits , i ve checked.

Thank you

Ok. So i rebuild the library using the following commands:

```
./configure --target=msp430 --prefix=/usr/local/Mymsp430
make
make install
```

Changed the LDFLAG to

```
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/Mymsp430/lib/ -lnettle
```

But i still have the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build the library with the same toolchain as the one you're using to build your application.

You can't link x86 code into code compiled for the MSP430, which is a totally different architecture.

Comment: excuse me ,but you are saying the ELF32-i368 is not compatible with theELF32-little

Comment: No, he's telling you that you are not only have the wrong elf format, but also the wrong instruction set. `readlef -h file` gives the required information. It should contain something like `Machine:                           Texas Instruments msp430 microcontroller`. Further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set

Comment: I still dont get it . Excuse me . What exactly i m suppose to do ? rebuild the library using different settings or ????